# Is it possible to add text in launch_background.xml (flutter)?

Tags: flutter

The question for me is, can I create a post in the launch_background.xml file to display when the page loads? I just managed to load the image and change the background color, I work with Flutter.

[picture my source here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5JsA.png)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use a text is to give it also as a Bitmap

```
<item  android:bottom="25dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/myText" />
</item>
```

where myText is just some text converted to an image (using paint or whatever)

Comment: I used this code that you put in my project and I got an error. Apart from this code, should there be any other changes?

Comment: Did you add an image file names myText to your drawable folder?